# Скрытие div при клике вне области

Tags: jquery

Есть код

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
var sl_number = '';
  if (!$(e.target).closest(".subclass").length) {
    $('.ja-magic-select').hide();
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Он скрывает .ja-magic-select, при нажатии вне div .subclass. Одна проблема, рядом находятся другие элементы с классом .subclass, и при нажатии например на первый элемент .subclass, а потом на второй элемент .subclass, первый .subclass не закрывается. Как сделать чтобы .ja-magic-select скрывался даже если мы нажимаем на другие элементы с классом  .subclass?

Comment: Класс в HTML - групповое понятие. Если нужно выделить какой-то из них, то  либо `ID`, либо `data-*`. Без выделения как можно понять что вон тот - нужный `.subclass`?

Comment: А если каждому subclass добавить id от num1 до num10, как переписать данный код?

Comment: Выбирать в `closest` вместо `.subclass` нужный `ID`.